# d3 force directed graph moving away on the svg, separating into group of nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My force directed graph is drawn correctly. But it doesn't stay still. I slightly moves here and there on the svg sometimes some nodes disappear from the visibility leaving clusters of nodes here and there. This is how the graph initially looks: [image]

Some time later it looks like this: nodes have gone every where away from the div [image]

```
var graph = new Object();
var map = new Object();
var index = 0;

var linkIndex = 0;

var width = $("#d3graph").width();
var height = $("#d3graph").height() ;


var svg = d3.select("#d3graph").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

// tool tip with the label
var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return d.name + "";
      })
svg.call(tip);

/* I take nodes and edges from outside. That part works fine*/

graph.links = dataset2;
graph.nodes = dataset1;

function drapGraph(graph) {

    svg.selectAll("g.link").remove();
    svg.selectAll("g.gnode").remove();

    var  force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .gravity(.05)
            .distance(30)
            .charge(-120)
            .size([width, height])
            .start();

    //map radius  domain--> range
    var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([d3.min(graph.nodes, function (d) {
              return Math.log(d.group);
          }), d3.max(graph.nodes, function (d) {
              return Math.log(d.group);
          })])
          .range([0, 30]);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(graph.links)
          .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .style("stroke-width", 2)
          .style("stroke-length", function (d) {return (10000/d.value);});

    var node = svg.selectAll("g.gnode")
          .data(graph.nodes)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "gnode")
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
          .call(force.drag);

    var maxretweets = d3.max(graph.nodes, function (d) {
        return Math.log(d.group);
    });
    var minretweets = d3.min(graph.nodes, function (d) {
        return Math.log(d.group);
    });
    var maxContent = d3.max(graph.nodes, function (d) {
        return d.degree;
    });
    var minvalue = d3.min(graph.links, function (d) {
        return d.value;
    });

    var circle = node.append("circle")
           .attr("r", function (d) {
               return rScale(Math.log(d.group));
           })
           .style("fill", function (d) {
               return d.color;

           })
            .style("stroke", "#000000")
           .on('mouseover', tip.show)
           .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
           .call(force.drag);

    //give you nodes with labels
    var label = node.append("text")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "8")
            .style("stroke", "#404040")
            .text(function (d) {
                if (rScale(Math.log(d.group)) > 5) {
                   return d.name;
                }
            });



    force.on("tick", function () {

        node.attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d.y;
        });

        circle.attr("cx", function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d.y;
        });

        label.attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y;
        });

        link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
    });

    svg.selectAll("g").attr("x", function (d) {
                                    return d.x;
                             })
                      .attr("y", function (d) {
                                 return d.y;
                                });
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? There is a small problem here but I couldn't figure out it, I tried so many things but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you simulate the problem in jsfiddle ?

Comment: are you sure all the data is related ? It may be that when it first initiates it looks like the first image, but when it settles all the related nodes are in the center whereas the unrelated are on the outside ?

Comment: There are some errors in your code: 1) For `svg:line` elements there is no style `stroke-length`. The length is determined by setting the start and end point of the line. 2) `node` is a d3 selection of `svg:g` elements which do not allow attributes `cx` and `cy`. These attributes are to be set on `circle`, which you already have taken care of. 3)  Similarly, `svg.selectAll("g")` cannot be used to set `x` and `y` attributes. These issues might or might not be related to your problem, but you should try to eliminate those beforehand.

Comment: Yes all ones are related. i want all the nodes to be seen. Gilsha's one worked. But nodes are moving here and there. They wanted to be still.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use bounded `x` and `y` values to fix such issues.

Try calculating `x` and `y` positions in tick function as shown below.

```
 node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
```

Refer [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492) for a sample.

**Edit:** There is no need to update the circle and text positions individually since they are grouped. Just need to update the group elements and links as follows.

```
force.on("tick", function () {
    svg.selectAll("g.node")
       .attr("transform", function (d) {
             d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x));
             d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y));
             return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";
       });   

    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
    });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked Gilsha! But now nodes are not disappearing. But they are moving here and there. I want them to come to a still position. Do you know any solution for that .

Comment: Edited the answer. Try now